# How can I drop 2-3 elements from a html node and scrape the rest?

Tags: r, rvest

To be precise, I have a class, say **A**, that I select via html_nodes in rvest. Now **A** can have many sub-classes and lots of html tags such as **links** and **img** tags. I want to drop some particular classes & tags from **A** while scraping the rest of the data. I do not know the classes for the rest of the data. I do know what I want to blacklist.

The HTML (hypothetical). This tag, `<div class="messageContent">` is repeated up to 25 times in the document, with differing content, but the same structure.

```
<div class="messageContent">
<article>
<blockquote class="messageText SelectQuoteContainer ugc baseHtml">
<div class="bbCodeBlock bbCodeQuote" data-author="Generic">

<aside>
<div class="attribution type">Generic said:
<a href="goto/post?id=32554#post-32754" class="AttributionLink">&uarr;</a>
</div>
<blockquote class="quoteContainer"><div class="quote">I see what you did there.</div><div class="quoteExpand">Click to expand...</div></blockquote>
</aside>

</div><img src="styles/default/xenforo/clear.png" class="mceSmilieSprite      mceSmilie9" alt=":o" title="Eek!    :o"/> Really?
<aside>
<div class="attribution type">Generic said:
<a href="goto/post?id=32554#post-32754" class="AttributionLink">&uarr;</a>
</div>
<blockquote class="quoteContainer"><div class="quote">I see what you did there.</div><div class="quoteExpand">Click to expand...</div></blockquote>
</aside>

<div class="messageTextEndMarker">&nbsp;</div>
</blockquote>
</article>
</div>
```

SO, the page I'm scraping contains multiple such classes. I do

```
posts <- page %>%  html_nodes(".messageContent")
```

This gives me a list of 25 html nodes, each containing variations of the aforementioned html content.

I want to remove everything within the `<aside>` & `</aside>` tags (which can occur at multiple places in the post), and capture the rest of the html via `html_text() %>% as.character()`

Can I do this with rvest?

Testing out @Mirosław Zalewski 's solution.

```
test<- page %>% html_node(".messageContent") %>%
          html_nodes(xpath='//*[not(ancestor::aside or name()="aside")]/text()')
```

This returned All of the elements of the page that were not within aside. A bit of fine-tuning, led me to:

```
page %>% html_nodes(xpath='(//div[@class="messageContent"])[1]//*[not(ancestor::aside or name()="aside")]/text()') %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
```

Iterated over the 25 classes, this gives me exactly what I need.

Comment: Please provide us a reproducible example to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XPath, you can select all nodes that are not `<aside>` or descendants of `<aside>`:

```
page %>% html_node(".messageContent") %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[not(ancestor::aside or name()="aside")]')
```

Unfortunately, this will match also elements that contain `<aside>`. If you pass that to `html_text()`, it will return `<aside>` text content anyway.

This can be overcome by adding another condition into query. One good candidate of such condition is "everything that is text node":

```
page %>% html_node(".messageContent") %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[not(ancestor::aside or name()="aside")]/text()')
```

Actually, `/text()` will return only text nodes, which pretty much allows you to skip `html_text()` call entirely. But since many text nodes are dubious (contain only whitespace characters) and this function has `trim` built-in, you might consider calling it anyway.

Please note that this solution will also skip any non-text content, such as image references (probably including emotes). Your original proposal would do that as well, but it is unclear to me whether you had intended that or not.

Comment: Your command is giving me a list of pretty much all the page's elements. (1.5mb, 2500 elements).  This command 
    
   `page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//article[not(ancestor::aside or name()="aside" or self::aside)]') %>% html_text() %>% as.character()`

This gives me a list of 25 containing the text of all posts, including the bits between `<aside> & </aside>` 

I've tried a few other combinations, but none have been able to deselect the `<aside>` nodes.

Comment: @user795028 all page elements except for `<aside>` and descendants of `<aside>`, which seems to be in line with your initial requirement. I don't understand what exactly is problem here - you could clarify in comment or edit initial question with more information. If that's easier for you, you can select all `<article>` that are direct children of some other element and then loop over them. I can imagine that function would take `<article>` element, select everything that is not (descendant of) `<aside>` and return text content of selected nodes.

Comment: `page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//article/*[not(parent::aside)]')` or `page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//article/*[not(parent::blockquote[@class="quoteContainer"])]')` isn't deselecting the relevant nodes either.

Comment: @user795028 sorry, but I am afraid there is nothing more I can do for you in these circumstances. You can try editing your initial post - add entire file you process (censored, if necessary) and exact results you expect to obtain. I don't understand how my solution is not suitable for you and your comments don't clear it up.

Comment: A slight fine-tuning of what you said led me to the answer. Took me a while to get it, since I'd never used xpath before. So, thanks. :)